# React-draggable components rendering off locations

Tags: reactjs

I made this app that renders 'word magnets' onto a fridge, the user can drag words to any part of the fridge to make a sentence and save it to local storage. The error occurs when the page is loaded, the word magnets are shifted out of position. The difference in positioning seems to be based on where the Word component is clicked on. If a user clicks on the top left corner the Word renders in the right place when reloaded but if the user clicks anywhere else on the Word component it will render out of place by how far away from the top right it is clicked. How can I change my component to render in the same position no matter where it was clicked?

```js
import React from 'react'
import Draggable from 'react-draggable'
import Scene from './Scene'
import Word from './Word'
import Header from './Header'

const FridgeMagnets = () => {
  const [dragWord, setDragWord] = React.useState('')
  const [words, setWords] = React.useState([])

  //set bounds for magnets
  const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth
  const bounds = {
    left: viewportWidth * 0.025,
    top: 15,
    right: viewportWidth * 0.44,
    bottom: viewportWidth
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    //check if there are words in local storage
    const localStorageWords = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('words'))
    if (localStorageWords) {
      setWords(localStorageWords)
    } else {
      setWords([
        { text: 'word', position: { x: 910, y: 210 }, id: 1 },
        { text: 'the', position: { x: 310, y: 210 }, id: 2 },
        { text: 'power', position: { x: 310, y: 510 }, id: 3 },
        { text: 'are', position: { x: 110, y: 610 }, id: 4 },
        { text: 'magnet', position: { x: 110, y: 650 }, id: 5 },
        { text: 'fridge', position: { x: 120, y: 700 }, id: 6 },
        { text: 'local', position: { x: 210, y: 410 }, id: 7 },
        { text: 'yes', position: { x: 310, y: 80 }, id: 8 }
      ])
    }
  }, [])

  //set the word to be moved
  const handleDrag = word => {
    setDragWord(word)
  }

  //update words array with new position for word
  const endPosition = position => {
    console.log(position.clientX, position.clientY, dragWord)
    //new position dragWord
    const updatedWords = words.map(word => {
      if (word === dragWord) {
        return {
          ...word,
          position: { x: position.clientX, y: position.clientY }
        }
      }
      return word
    })
    setWords(updatedWords)
  }

  //save words to local storage
  const handleSave = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('words', JSON.stringify(words))
  }

  return (
    <Scene>
      <div className="relative">
        <Header />
      </div>
      {words.map((word, index, id) => {
        return (
          <Draggable
            key={index}
            onDrag={() => handleDrag(word)}
            defaultPosition={word.position}
            bounds={bounds}
            onStop={position => endPosition(position)}
          >
            <div>
              <Word text={word.text} id={id} />
            </div>
          </Draggable>
        )
      })}
      <button onClick={handleSave}>save</button>
    </Scene>
  )
}

export default FridgeMagnets
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting the offsetX and offsetY from the client positions solved this.

```js
  const endPosition = position => {
    //add new position dragWord, subtract offset to get correct position
    const updatedWords = words.map(word => {
      if (word === dragWord) {
        return {
          ...word,
          position: {
            x: position.clientX - position.offsetX,
            y: position.clientY - position.offsetY
          }
        }
      }
      return word
    })
    setWords(updatedWords)
  }
```